# what does is it have to do with the screen size

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
from turtle import right
import pyautogui, time, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
time.sleep(3)
class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Square,self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20,20))
    self.surf.fill((255,0,0))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
width,height = 960,540
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
cont = True
square1 = Square()
while cont:
time.sleep(0.4)
x,y=random.randrange(int(1920/2- 
width/2),int(1920/2+width/2)),random.randrange(int(1080/2-height/2),int(1080/2+height/2))
screen.blit(square1.surf,(x,y))
pyautogui.click(x,y)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        cont=False
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
            cont=False
pygame.display.flip()
```

I am new to Python, now learning the basic pyautogui usage and tried making this useless 'game' which was supposed to move the cursor to some point and draw a square at this point and everything is working completely fine when screen size is set to (1920,1080), but when I change the size to anything else it just fails, like cursor coordinates and square being drawn coordinates are not compatible. Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: and can you possibly explain why cursor and square coordinates do not match? shouldn't they if they are initialized from the same variables? (x,y)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you draw a square in a pygame window that has its coordinates (0,0), but the cursor has the coordinates (0,0) of your entire screen. I solve it, that I draw first square with pygame window coordinates and then I couted shift.

Here is my code example:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.4)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

    square1.rect.x = random.randint(0, width - square1.rect.w)
    square1.rect.y = random.randint(0, height - square1.rect.h)

    pyautogui.click((1920/2 - width/2) + square1.rect.centerx,
                (1080/2-height/2) + square1.rect.centery)

    screen.blit(square1.surf, square1.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

If you have pygame window size same like your entire size, it works becouse coordinates (0,0) are on the same place.

I hope it will help you, Adam

PS: If you move pygame window it not works, because in counting I presuppose, that pygame screen is in center your entire screen.